# placeholder on input text field with if condition

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a input field, i have given a placeholder to it as seen below

```
<ion-input 
[(ngModel)]="myname" 
type="text" 
#newName (keyup.enter)="save(newName.value); newName.value='' " 
placeholder="Name">
</ion-input>
```

I want to add if condition in placeholder but dont know how to do it

In my `page.ts` file, i have a variable `{{myname}}`, i want placeholder to show that vaue if it is not null else `placeholder="Name"`

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Where you able to solve this? If so, could you please mark any answer as accepted, so we can close the issue? :)

Answer (score 6):

below way will work:

```
placeholder="{{myname ? myname : Name}}"
```

Comment: AFAIK, using string interpolation is not the recommended way to bind attributes/properties in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that like this:

```
<ion-input [placeholder]="myname ? myname : 'Name'" ...></ion-input>
```